# Filter data frame and append result to existing lists R

Tags: r

I want to filter a dataframe column (col_A) and append the output to existing lists. The filters to apply to col_A are included in a vector col_A_filters.

My question is how to create a function for this with R.

Example:

```
Df <- data.frame(
  col_A = c("abc","def"),
  col_B = c(123,456)
)

# existing lists:
abc <- list()
def <- list()


col_A_filters <- c("abc", "def")
```

The output should be that to each of the lists abc and def the filtered rows of Df are added.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way with `mget` and `append`.

```r
Df <- data.frame(
  col_A = c("abc","def"),
  col_B = c(123,456)
)

# existing lists:
abc <- list()
def <- list()

col_A_filters <- c("abc", "def")

l <- mget(col_A_filters, envir = .GlobalEnv)
for(i in col_A_filters) {
  new <- Df[Df$col_A == i, ]
  l[[i]] <- append(l[[i]], new)
  l[[i]] <- as.data.frame(l[[i]])
}
list2env(l, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

abc
#>   col_A col_B
#> 1   abc   123

def
#>   col_A col_B
#> 1   def   456
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `{purrr}`:

```
library(tidyverse)
col_A_filters <- c("abc", "def")
x <- col_A_filters |> 
  as.list()|> 
  map(~Df |> 
        filter(str_detect(col_A, .x))) |> 
  set_names(col_A_filters)

y <- mget(col_A_filters, envir = .GlobalEnv)
map2(l, x, append) |> map(as.data.frame)
```

**Output**:

```
$abc
  col_A col_B
1   abc   123

$def
  col_A col_B
1   def   456
```

Comment: This solution does the first part (filter a dataframe column (col_A), but how to append the output to the existing lists?

Comment: You are completely right, sorry about that. I only can think of a similar solution as @Rui using `mget`. I make a small edit.